# How to pass parameters from main process to render processes in Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app that can open different windows.

On app launch the app open a set of window(s) (that load the same HTML and JS files) but with params to change each window displayed infos.

Example :

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
  ...
  // open window for stuff 1
  win1 = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1024,
     height: 728
  });
  win1.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/app.html?id=1`);

  // open window for stuff 2
  win2 = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 1024,
     height: 728
  });
  win2.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/app.html?id=2`);
```

Obviously passing params in file:// path doesn't work.
I can't find a clear solution in Electron documentation or elsewhere on Internet to condition my rendered window to a param.

I can probably use IPC communication after window ready but it seems a little bit too complicated until I just want pass a variable to my child view.

P.S. : to be totally honest my application is built with React/Redux and the param I want to pass to view is the redux store key to listen for this view.

Comment: Passing params (and a hash) in the `file://` path works just fine for me. All params are in `location` as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't use this parameterized URL concept for a file, if you would provide them on an HTTP Server ok. Instead you could do different things, e.g. use Cookies, read them on start. Or just use win1.webContents.executeJavaScript("var query = {id:1}")... at least it is a one liner

Comment: I think both of your answer made the deal.

Comment: I don't see any problems with providing (short) parameters to a `file://`; That said I also use a `preload` script file from which I get a (possibly large) JSON page data string from the main thread and make it available to the page. This way the page data is available already during page load.

Comment: You seem to be asking the same question every 4 hours. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKzBJAowmGg

Comment: Electron's context bridge worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70217434/470749

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According atom source code the query string method is a reliable way to do that very simply, especially when we only need to pass a unique string param:

```
// main process
win1.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/app.html?id=${id}`);

// rendered process
console.log(global.location.search);
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6504

Comment: better to be received as json object. Is there a way to achieve so?

Comment: @MagedSaeed yes, use global varialbe (check my answer below)

Answer (score 56):

A few methods:

### loadURL Query String

[The query string method others have posted seems to work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335004/how-to-pass-parameters-from-main-process-to-render-processes-in-electron/38401579#38401579). It might even be the easiest.

### additionalArguments

Electron's documentation says `additionalArguments` is:

> Useful for passing small bits of data down to renderer process preload
>   scripts.

**Main**

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: '#000000'
  webPreferences: {
    additionalArguments: ["myvarvalue", "secondvarvalue", "--another=something"]
  }
});
```

**Renderer**

`window.process.argv` is going to look something like:

```
["--num-raster-threads=2",
"--enable-gpu-memory-buffer-compositor-resources",
"--enable-gpu-async-worker-context",
...
"--renderer-client-id=4",
"myvarvalue",
"secondvarvalue",
"--another=something"]
```

It will append an array of strings. You could do something `window.process.argv.slice(-3)` to grab the last items in the array.

---

### IPC Main / Render

Like you said, it seems complicated for what you are trying to do, but maybe this helps:

**Main**

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron');

var mainProcessVars = {
  somevar: "name",
  anothervar: 33
}

ipcMain.on('variable-request', function (event, arg) {
  event.sender.send('variable-reply', [mainProcessVars[arg[0]], mainProcessVars[arg[1]]]);
});
```

**Renderer**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;

electron.ipcRenderer.send('variable-request', ['somevar', 'anothervar']);

ipcRenderer.on('variable-reply', function (event, args) {
  console.log(args[0]); // "name"
  console.log(args[1]); // 33
});
```

This way allows you to send data besides strings.

Comment: `window.process` is undefined in renderer nowadays unless `webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false }`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612493/process-is-not-defined-for-electrons-getting-started-app

Comment: @PsychoX I'ts true that `process` is undefined in renderer, but it can be accessed in preload script. You can then expose that (safely?) to renderer via `contextBridge`.

Comment: `additionalArguments` work well, but I noticed that on Windows (or at least on my colleague's setup) there would be an additional argument (`/prefetch:1`) appended _after_ them, so `slice(-3)` is not a reliable way of reading them.

Comment: `additionalArguments` is great. as @BartvanHeukelom suggested, I'd add a prefix to each string, for example "id=", and replace `.slice()` with `let idArray = process.argv.filter((str) => str.startsWith('id='));`

Answer (score 17):

Using query string along with `win.loadFile()`,

```
// main process or renderer process 1
data = {"age": 12, "healthy": true}

let win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true
        }
      });

win.loadFile("public/print.html", {query: {"data": JSON.stringify(data)}});
```

```
// renderer process 2
const querystring = require('querystring');
let query = querystring.parse(global.location.search);
let data = JSON.parse(query['?data'])
```

Comment: Is there a limit to how much data may be passed on the query string? Thanks!

Comment: @majorBummer I'm not sure. I never hit the limit.

Comment: I used this until it turned out to suffer from inappropriate caching. That is, the value of `location.search` (which in my case should be different every time I run the program) would be that of a previous invocation.

Comment: `querystring is now deprecated.`
The `querystring` API is considered Legacy. While it is still maintained, new code should use the `URLSearchParams` API instead.

Answer (score 3):

We can inject Javascript code execution (on window `did-finish-load` event) and trigger react re-rendering with correct redux state portion. But it requires additional lifecycle step in rendered process.

Using hash or query in "local filepath" sounds a little bit weird but in my case it take sense since the hash describe the redux store branch to take in consideration in this window (`file://which-code-to-load#which-content`).

So even if i'm not totally at ease with this approach right now I'll take the second option.

It's a shame that the API doesn't provide any way to declare global vars from main process on window opening. I'll post a feature request.

Comment: can you elaborate / give examples for how these would work?

Answer (score 2):

Actually use the invoke and handle combo can work as well. In my example, i especially need to establish a connection at the very beginning.

In preload

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ipcRenderer.invoke('init').then(res => {
    window.alert(res)
    // render(e(App, {}), elem)
  })
})
```

And in main

```js
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

ipcMain.handle('init', async () => {
  return 'Abc'
})
```

You might even try to make a sync call via `ipcRenderer.sendSync`, maybe this is quicker, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

**Process script**

In your main script write:

```
global.varsForWindow = {
    platform: process.platform
};
```

**Window script**

Where you need it in a window script:

```
var varsFromMainScript = require('electron').remote.getGlobal('varsForWindow');
console.log(varsFromMainScript.platform);
```

Comment: Doesn't work if you need to pass different values to different windows...

Answer (score 1):

You can share data between main and renderer processor using `global` variable:

Main processor:

```
global.id = 1;
```

Renderer processor:

```
let id = remote.getGlobal('id');
```

Comment: I don't recommend this way. if developers want to create multiple windows consecutively.

Comment: the remote module has been deprecated and is no longer recommended for use

Comment: besides, what is remote? another global?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a new instance of BrowserWindow the query parameters don't seem to work at least in these versions:

```
"electron": "^26.2.2",
"nextron": "^8.12.0",
```

The workaround I found was to pass parameters through additionalArguments

```
      webPreferences: {
        additionalArguments: [
          `--metadata=${JSON.stringify(arg.data)}`,
        ],
      },
```

Then on your preload script

```
const metadata = process.argv.filter((arg) => arg.startsWith('--metadata='))[0]?.split('=')?.[1]
const data = JSON.parse(metadata || '{}')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('appInfo', {
  metadata: data,
})
```

And then you can get it on your component with

```
global.appInfo.metadata
```

Answer (score -5):

Unfortunately, it seems pretty complicated. You probably won't be able to add variables to .html you render in electron in a nice way.

Of course - you can use url but it slows down booting very much (vy seconds) or you can execute Javascript in BrowserWindo, which also slows boot down.

The only way is the IPC and leaving javascript .html agnostic to variables from main process. Very sad though..