# Send environment variable value to renderer thread in Electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app. I need to get the value of an environment variable from my local machine to use on the renderer thread. I want to pass this value to the renderer thread when the app starts. I know in the `main.js` file, I can get the environment variable like this:

**main.js**

```
const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });
  
    win.loadFile('index.html');

    // Retrieve the environment variable value
    const variableValue = process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE;
    console.log(`Variable value: ${variableValue}`);

    // Send the variable and it's value to the renderer.
    win.webContents.send('initialize', { 'variableName':variableValue });
}
```

The above successfully prints the environment variable's value to the terminal window. However, I need to use this value in the browser side of the ball. How do I get the variable's value there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't be done directly from the renderer process (with `nodeIntegration` off), since it has no direct access to the Node.js `process` variable.

The most straightforward way to do this is via the BrowserWindow's preload script, which allows you to expose arbitrary data to the renderer process via Electron's `contextBridge` API. An example:

```js
// Main Process
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'); // require `path` if you haven't already
  }
});
```

```js
// Preload Script
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');

// this should print out the value of MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
console.log(process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE);

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('envVars', {
  myEnvironmentVariable: process.env.MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
});
```

```js
// Renderer Process
console.log(window.envVars.myEnvironmentVariable)
```

See the contextBridge API docs: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge

Comment: This should be `console.log(window.envVars.myEnvironmentVariable)`.

Comment: I believe that the main code should specify the preload script in the `webPreferences` object.